# JQuery load() function disables links and :hover effects?

Tags: css, jquery

I'm trying to load content from a different file into a div element within the current file using the jQuery load() function. Nothing fancy, just loading it and that's it. However the links that are contained in the loaded file become "disabled",  you cannot click them, and pseudo-classes like :hover seem to be left out as well. Is there a solution to this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.content").load("content.html");
});
```

let's say content.html contains just this line:

```
<a href="somelink.html">xxx</a>
```

When it is loaded into the `<div class="content">` the link is not clickable. It is colored according to the css, however the :hover effect doesn't work, and it behaves like normal text - not a link. This is a problem because the content I'm trying to load has a couple of links, and none of them work after being load()'ed.

Comment: What does "links become disabled" mean? It's hard to say where your error is.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please post some sample code to back your query so that some pragmatic suggestions can be provided to you rather than hunches based on the description.

Comment: You can't load links with `.load()`, sorry... no, just kidding `:P`. Check the DOM tree in the browser's dev tools. Does the DIV contain an A (ANCHOR) element? *** Regarding the :hover styles, what selector(s) exactly do you use on your page? Can you confirm that the inserted anchor is supposed to be matched by that/those selector(s)?

Comment: The regular styling works but `:hover` does not? Can you provide a demo (e.g. on jsFiddle)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is:

- You use $('div.content').load('content.html') to send a request for content to (later) be inserted into the DOM.
- You then run some code to specify handlers for nodes using $(document).click, $(document).bind etc - but this code runs before the new nodes have been added to the DOM.
- New nodes are then added when the .load call completes.
- The behaviour that you defined on all the *origional* nodes isn't being followed on the *new* nodes.

If that is the issue your're describing - then you need to add all the same bindings to the new nodes once they're created.

i.e. you need to provide a callback to add the bindings to the new elements:

```
function on_data_loaded() {
    $('div.content ...').hover(.....);
    // etc.
}
$('div.content').load('content.html', null, onloaded);
```

(note that's not a particularly clean way of doing it, but it should explain what needs to be done).

Comment: Hmm - `$(document)` should always work; moreover, binding to `:hover` is not really deterministic as it depends on where the user's cursor is at the time you're binding events.

Comment: I didn't do $(document) in the callback because the rest of the dom has already had the callbacks added.

apologies for the :hover in the selector too - I actually meant to add a .hover() call - I'll modify the answer now